# Multiple day values in a row in mysql table a good idea or not?

Tags: mysql

The following question with respect to my limited mysql database design experience.

I have setup a mysql table with saves a unique data value for each day for each user, see the simplified example below. The user's private webpage  will retrieve a number of data values within a defined period, which could be up to (the last) 365 days and even more.

table fields:

```
id  userid dayval1  dayval2  dayval3 ...dayval31  date
```

My reason for saving 31 day values in one record (instead of a single record for each dayvalue) was to to save server processing power/server cost; for a period of say 365 days only 12 records instead of 365 records need to be retrieved for each user each day, and in a few years there could be 10.000 users (rough crystal ball user forefast).

Then I noticed the (php and javascript) code for saving, retrieving and processing the dayvalues with this table structure is getting relatively complex (at least more complex than with a single record for each dayvalue, and I start questioning my made choice: would this table structure indeed save significant server processing power and cost, or will the gain be minimal and I better go for the single record design?

I could also rephrase this question: what aspects determine the cost of server&database software the most? (is it server processing capacity as I assumed, or memory storage capacity or perhaps (my)sql database software licenses?)

Comment: What kind of values are you storing? Large amounts of information like this is probably best stored in a string. Then your server can parse the string if you're worried about stress on the database.

Comment: @WBO Co: each dayvalue is of type INT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically trying to reinvent a mature feature of a RDBMS in a less effective language.

You can actually measure this, but I bet MySQL is far better suited to handle millions of properly indexed rows than the PHP code to extract the day-to-day data. And consider you're only saving an order of magnitude on the record count.

(By properly indexed I mean something like `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX date_users_days ON data(user_id, date)`)

Comment: thnx (!) I did not know the CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement. I just read at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp "Note: Updating a table with indexes takes more time than updating a table without (because the indexes also need an update). So you should only create indexes on columns (and tables) that will be frequently searched against." I my case the the table is updated night (and read every day). IS your suggestion still optimal with this in mind?

Comment: Yes - the writes aren't affected much, but searching through a million of records without an index will be extremely slow.

Comment: Ok, in that case I'll follow your suggestion with the CREATE INDEX and one record per dayvalue. Just a final question: How does this UNIQUE INDEX works from the search perspective? Does the UNIQUE INDEX work under the hood when searching and do I define the same queries a before, or is a special kind of search statement needed?

Comment: The index is used automatically, you can prepend any mysql query with `EXPLAIN ` to check that: `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`. See the [mysql documentation on indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization-indexes.html) for further details.